# Uniform Cost Search: How do I retain the solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

The algorithm can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search

I am struggling with keeping the solution. I am writing in Python, and my implementation finds the optimal solution as expected, but I don't know how to store it.

I would imagine when exploring new neighbors, I need to add the current node to the new neighbors paths, however it isn't working how I expect.

It is a homework assignment so I won't post code yet, but if it is necessary for your help I can post snippets.

Thanks!

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. What do you mean "keeping the solution"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for finding the final path? In that case you can just store the address of the parent node in each node and traverse upwards to root when you find the destination.